# how to extract an XPATH from an html page with Saxon-PE commandline

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, saxon, basex

I would like to extract the XPATH //DIV[@id="ps-content"] out from this web page: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449319432](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319432) (saved as a local file)

I would like to do it with a single line of command-line with one of the best parsers, like Saxon-PE or BaseX.

So far the shortest solution that I (seemed to have) found is with these two lines:

```
java -jar tagsoup-1.2.1.jar <page.html >page.xhtml"
java -cp saxon9pe.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"page.xhtml" -qs:"//DIV[@id='ps-content']"
```

but all what it returns is this, that is not my expected block of html code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

My questions are two:

- what's wrong with my command-lines? why they doesn't return the expected block of html code as defined by my XPATH?
- since Saxon-PE has embedded TagSoup capability (see https://www.odesk.com/leaving-odesk?ref=http%253A%252F%252Fsaxonica.com%252Fdocumentation9.4-demo%252Fhtml%252Fextensions%252Ffunctions%252Fparse-html.html), how can I integrate my two lines into a single line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract an XPATH from an html page with BaseX commandline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014152/how-to-extract-an-xpath-from-an-html-page-with-basex-commandline)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. The problem is the same for both Saxon and BaseX, the solution I posted in the answer for BaseX also applies to Saxon.

Comment: Still can't make it work.  I tried with this updated command-line: java -cp saxon9pe.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:'doc("test.xhtm")//*:div[id@"ps-content"]'  and all what it returns is this string "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>doc(test.xhtm)//*:div[id@ps-content]"

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct command-line to launch the query without TagSoup:

```
java -cp saxon9pe.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"test.xhtm" -qs:"//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
```

Note that inverting the type of quotes like this doesn't work (in Win7):

```
java -cp saxon9pe.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"test.xhtm" -qs:'//*:div[@id="ps-content"]'
```

Does anyone know how to add the TagSoup preprocess in the same command-line?

Answer (score -1):

My last **failed** attempts to integrate TagSoup in the same command-line:

```
...\SaxonPE9-4-0-7J>java -cp saxon9pe.jar;tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
 net.sf.saxon.Query --xqueryVersion:3.0 -qs:"saxon:parse-html(fn:unparsed-text('
page.html'))//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
Error on line 1 column 17
  XPST0017 XQuery static error near #...:unparsed-text('page.html'))//#:
    System function unparsed-text#1 is not available with this host language/ver
sion
Static error(s) in query
```

---

```
...\SaxonPE9-4-0-7J>java -cp saxon9pe.jar;tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
 net.sf.saxon.Query --xqueryVersion:3.0 -qs:"fn:parse-html(fn:unparsed-text('pag
e.html'))//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
Error on line 1 column 14
  XPST0017 XQuery static error near #...:unparsed-text('page.html'))//#:
    System function unparsed-text#1 is not available with this host language/ver
sion
Static error(s) in query
```

---

```
...\SaxonPE9-4-0-7J>java -cp saxon9pe.jar;tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
 net.sf.saxon.Query --xqueryVersion:3.0 -qs:"saxon:parse-html(collection('page.h
tml;unparsed=yes'))//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
Error on line 1 of *module with no systemId*:
  FODC0002: The file or directory
  file:/C:/Users/diego/Downloads/SaxonPE9-4-0-7J/page.html;unparsed=yes does not
 exist
Query processing failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

---

```
...\SaxonPE9-4-0-7J>java -cp saxon9pe.jar;tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
 net.sf.saxon.Query --xqueryVersion:3.0 -qs:"saxon:parse-html(collection('page.h
tml';'unparsed=yes'))//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
Error on line 1 column 39
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...ion('page.html';'unparsed=yes'#:
    expected ")", found ";"
Static error(s) in query
```