# how to extract an XPATH from an html page with BaseX commandline

Tags: xml, xpath, xhtml, basex

I would like to extract the XPATH //DIV[@id="ps-content"] out from this web page: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449319432](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319432) (saved as a local file)

I would like to do it with a single line of command-line with one of the best parsers, like BaseX or Saxon-PE.

So far the shortest solution that I (seemed to have) found is with these two lines:

```
java -jar tagsoup-1.2.1.jar <page.html >page.xhtml"
basex -ipage.xhtml "//DIV[@id='ps-content']"
```

but all what it returns is an empty line, instead than my expected block of html code:

My questions are two:

- what's wrong with my command-lines? why they doesn't return the expected block of html code as defined by my XPATH?
- since BaseX has embedded TagSoup capability (see https://www.odesk.com/leaving-odesk?ref=http%253A%252F%252Fdocs.basex.org%252Fwiki%252FParsers%2523HTML_Parser), how can I integrate my two lines into a single line?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your query:

1. **Tagsoup adds namespaces**

   Either register the namespace (it seems reasonable to declare the default namespace as you're probably only dealing with XHTML):

   ```
   basex -ipage.xhtml "declare default element namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'; //div[@id='ps-content']"
   ```

   or use `*` as namespace indicator for each element:

   ```
   basex -ipage.xhtml "//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
   ```
2. **XML/XQuery is case sensitive**

   I already corrected it in my queries in (1): `<div/>` is not the same as `<DIV/>`. Both queries in (1) already yield the expected result.

---

Tagsoup can be used from within BaseX, you do not have to call it separately for HTML-input. Make sure to include tagsoup in your default Java classpath, eg. by installing `libtagsoup-java` in Debian.

```
basex 'declare option db:parser "html"; doc("page.html")//*:div[@id="ps-content"]'
```

You can even query the HTML page directly from BaseX if you want to:

```
basex 'declare option db:parser "html"; doc("http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449319432")//*:div[@id="ps-content"]'
```

Using `-i` didn't work for me with using tagsoup, but you can use `doc(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your great help... however I've still no luck (or more likely no suff. experience) to make any of your command-line work.
Even the simplest "basex -ipage.xhtml "//*:div[@id='ps-content']" returns an empty line...  but I noticed that even with a not existant file like -ifoo.bar it's the same!  why does it return no error?

Comment: Btw I'm on Win7 and I copied the file tagsoup-1.2.1.jar to the BaseX/bin folder. How can now include it in my default Java classpath?

Comment: Your last command-line returns this error: 
c:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\bin>basex 'declare option db:parser "html"; doc("ht
tp://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449319432")//*:div[@id="ps-content"]'
Stopped at line 1, column 8:
[XPST0003] Expecting quote.

Comment: That should work, maybe it's an quoting issue with Windows' command prompt. Haven't got any Windows around, so cannot test it. tagsoup should go to the lib folder. If it's in there, it should be included automatically. Did you try using the GUI to verify the command? If doing so, create a database with the file instead of using -i.

Comment: I see that there's already a "tagsoup-1.2.jar" in the lib folder. If I change it to the new "tagsoup-1.2.1.jar" does it automatically take the new automatically?

Comment: Oh, I retried today and now I your first two examples works!  while your last two examples still gives the usual "Stopped at line 1, column 8: [XPST0003] Expecting quote." even if all the quotes appears balanced...

Comment: I'm getting an "Invalid document URI" error as there's whitespace in the protocol identifier. Did you copy/paste the line?

Comment: FOUND! I just had to invert the type of quotes, like this: basex "declare option db:parser 'html'; doc('page.html')//*:div[@id='ps-content']"   (who knows why?! I always used both ways in other programs without problems)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the right command-line:

```
basex "declare option db:parser 'html'; doc('page.html')//*:div[@id='ps-content']"
```

Note: inverting the type of quotes like this doesn't work in my Win7:

```
basex 'declare option db:parser "html"; doc("page.html")//*:div[@id="ps-content"]'
```