# how to combine two XPATH queries to avoid parsing two times a long XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0

I have a long local XML file like this:

```
<root>
  <div>this</div>
  <div>is</div>
  <div>a</div>
  ...
  <div>very</div>
  <div>long</div>
  <div>list</div>
</root>
```

I need to know:

1. the total number of thos div elements
2. the position of the element "very"

I know that I can do that by launching these two XPATH (2.0) queries:

```
1.  count(/root/div)
2.  index-of(/root/div,"very")
```

but the XML file is long so I hate that the XML parsing engine passes two times through all the file.

Is there a faster combination that returns for example an array with the two results, passing a single time through the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XQUERY language:

```
let $div := /root/div
return
<result>
<cnt>{count($div)}</cnt>
<v-index>{index-of($div, contains(., 'very'))}</v-index>
</result>
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you have to parse the XML document twice in order to run two XPath queries? I don't know what API you are using to run the XPath, but I don't know of an API that has that restriction.

Comment: My logic tells me that if I launch two times a command-line XPATH query over a local XML file on my harddisk, the file will be read and parsed two times, with the only advantage of HD caching the second time...
I still don't even know if there's a way to launch two queries in a single command-line launch because I've to solve a bigger problem first: to make a (simpler) command-line query work. For example with Saxon I even asked for help here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013688/how-to-extract-an-xpath-from-an-html-page-with-saxon-pe-commandline  but without luck so far...

Comment: Correct, you don't want to do this from the command line. Take a look at something like xmlsh.

Comment: I need to call it from a proprietary scripting language... so a single-line command-line would be better...
According to this page http://www.xmlsh.org/XPathExtension XMLSH only supports "Version 0.1.0.0 an XPath" so the function "index-of" used in my example is not supported.  Correct?

Comment: I can't help you with xmlsh, but I think you are misreading the spec. You don't need XPath extensions, and that version number is an xmlsh version number not an XPath version number.

Comment: Ah, you're right about xmlsh version, however xmlsh seems a very unpopular tool to deserve learning it. What about the XQUERY that I just posted? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17116961/1292671

Comment: You can certainly achieve a lot more with XQuery than with XPath, but eventually, doing this from the command line is going to run out of steam. It's hard to believe that's the right long-term approach.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, or at least I doubt it.

Long answer: It can be done in a single pass, but only by whatever is calling the XPath. In pseudo code:

```
FIND ALL DIVS USING XPath(/root/div), ASSIGN TO x
VAR i = 0
VAR v = -1
LOOP THROUGH ALL x
    INCREMENT COUNTER i
    IF x' EQUALS 'very' AND v EQUALS -1
        v = i
```

Comment: would it be sufficient for me to convert that to an XQUERY?

Comment: Should be fine to do that, if you are using XQuery.